# How to install 16-bit XAMPP on Windows 95?

Tags: xampp, dosbox, windows-95

I need to install XAMPP on my Windows 95 running on my iPhone. I am 100% sure this is possible as I was able to get Visual Basic 4.0 installed on my DosBox for iPhone.

I don't need MySQL, but I do need PHP. And I need to run .php pages locally.

If there is a faster XAMPP-like program for Windows 95 that runs PHP only, I am all for it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken?

Comment: Yes sir. I already have Lighttpd installed on it, but I wanna install XAMPP specifically on the Windows 95 so I can develop the Visual Basic 4 and point it to the local server.

Comment: Alright. I wanted to recommend you lighttpd. :)

Comment: Oh I already have that and most other compilers on Cydia.

Comment: I would recommend you to install Windows 98 and install xampp on it.
http://www.oldapps.com/xampp.php?old_xampp=44 There you can find the old xampp-version. But you can't use mysql. But as you said, you dont need it. It that fits your question, I will add it as an answer. :)

Comment: The thing is that Windows 98 is almost 50% slower and almost unusable.

Comment: Added an answer that should be good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WAMP-Server](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-1318-wamp-server) (WAMP means Windows Apache MySQL **PHP**)should be, what you are looking for. It is compatible with Windows 95 so you can install it easily. Also WAMP includes MySQL if you ever need it.